# Missing AndroidManifest File ApkSigner Exception

Tags: android, github-actions, digital-signature, android-app-bundle

I am trying to publish a `multi-modular` Android app using GitHub Actions Workflow to Playstore.

I was initially getting this signing error:

```
Run r0adkll/upload-google-play@v1
Creating a new Edit for this release
Validating track 'production'
Uploading app-release.aab
Error: The Android App Bundle was not signed. Please sign the bundle using jarsigner.
```

This prompted me to check if the **`aab`** file was signed correctly.

I added these 2 workflow steps to check if the **`aab`** file *exists* and also *extract aab files*.

```
 -  name: Check AAB Existence
     run: ls -l app/build/outputs/bundle/release/
            
  - name: Extract the contents of the AAB
     run: unzip -l app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab
```

This is the verification step on the workflow.

```
- name: Verify Signature
   run: $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/build-tools/34.0.0/apksigner verify --print-certs --verbose app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab
```

From the above 2 steps I confirmed that the **`aab`** file does exist and the `Android Manifest.xml` file is also present.

[image]

However, this error persists even after *Cleaning* and *Rebuilding* my project.

```
Run $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/build-tools/34.0.0/apksigner verify --print-certs --verbose app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab
Error: Exception in thread "main" com.android.apksig.apk.ApkFormatException: Missing AndroidManifest.xml
    at com.android.apksig.ApkSigner.getAndroidManifestFromApk(ApkSigner.java:970)
    at com.android.apksig.ApkVerifier.getAndroidManifestFromApk(ApkVerifier.java:1225)
```

Here are the links to my `workflow.yaml` and `app gradle.build.kts`

- [Workflow](https://github.com/Tonnie-Dev/CountriesPad/tree/master/.github/workflows)
- [App gradle.build](https://github.com/Tonnie-Dev/CountriesPad/blob/master/app/build.gradle.kts)

Kindly help me narrow down what I may doing wrong.

Comment: What stage do you sign it?

Comment: Hi @JakeB, Thx for checking, pls see this [build run](https://github.com/Tonnie-Dev/CountriesPad/actions/runs/7098362878/job/19320175834#step:11:10). I'm doing `version bump` -> `Build & Sign` -> `Check aab` -> `Verify Signature`. The issue is the missing **manifest file** at _Verify Signature_ stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned the hard way that **`ApkSigner`** is primarily designed to work with **`APK`** (*Android Package Kit*) files and not with **`.aab`** (*Android App Bundle*) files.

To verify `.aab` files, you can go for [Bundletool](https://github.com/google/bundletool) which is a command-line tool provided by Google.

However, what worked for me was first signing the `.aab` with this step:

```
- name: Sign AAb
           id: sign
           uses: r0adkll/sign-android-release@v1
           with:
              releaseDirectory: app/build/outputs/bundle/release
              signingKeyBase64: ${{ secrets.KEYSTORE }}
              alias: ${{ secrets.SIGNING_KEY_ALIAS }}
              keyStorePassword: ${{ secrets.SIGNING_STORE_PASSWORD }}
              keyPassword: ${{ secrets.SIGNING_KEY_PASSWORD }}
```

I then simply used **`job.status`** to verify the status:

```
- run: echo "Build status report=${{ job.status }}."
```

This was the result for success:

```
Run echo "Build status report=success."
  echo "Build status report=success."
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    JAVA_HOME: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk/18.0.2-101/x64
    JAVA_HOME_18_X64: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk/18.0.2-101/x64
    GRADLE_BUILD_ACTION_SETUP_COMPLETED: true
    GRADLE_BUILD_ACTION_CACHE_RESTORED: true
    SIGNED_RELEASE_FILE: app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab
Build status report=success.
```

This was the result for a failed signing job:

```
Run echo "Build status report=failure"
```

You can review the entire workflow [here.](https://github.com/Tonnie-Dev/CountriesPad/blob/master/.github/workflows/publishing_workflow.yaml)

Cheers.